# Detecting Font size in android using Tesseract+Leptonica

Tags: android, fonts, ocr, tesseract, leptonica

I'm making an android app to perform OCR on text using Tessearact and Leptonica(for binarization and Otsu thresholding) libraries. so my question is: Can I detect or atleast differentiate (larger/ smaller) between the font sizes that the app reads?

Comment: Hi, I need to scan small text from the hard copy(hard copy like current bills,etc...). I am using this github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr Project. How to scan smaller text ?I am struck here.Please help me ASAP.Thanks in Advance.